# Reading Specific Data In XML Files in Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net, file, parsing

The title says it all, I want to know how to read various pieces of data from .xml files in visual basic. My current, basic, xml file looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<ArrayOfActivity xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


 -<activity>

 <memno>1239</memno>

 <curweek>0</curweek>

 <rundist>0</rundist>

 <runtime>0</runtime>

 <swimdist>0</swimdist>

 <swimtime>0</swimtime>

 <cycdist>0</cycdist>

 <cyctime>0</cyctime>

 </activity>


 -<activity>

 <memno>1293</memno>

 <curweek>0</curweek>

 <rundist>0</rundist>

 <runtime>0</runtime>

 <swimdist>0</swimdist>

 <swimtime>0</swimtime>

 <cycdist>0</cycdist>

 <cyctime>0</cyctime>
 </activity>
 </ArrayOfActivity>
```

I want to just read to values from, say, member number 1239, how do I go about this? I cannot make sense of any on-line help, I am fairly new to visual basic. I also save through this method:

```
 Public Sub SaveDataAct()
    If System.IO.File.Exists("e:\Test\test2.xml") = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete("e:\Test\test2.xml")
    End If
    Dim serializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of activity)))
    Dim fs As New IO.FileStream("e:\Test\test2.xml", IO.FileMode.Create)
    serializer.Serialize(fs, dataentry)
    fs.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Post the xml as text using the icon with two arrows <> instead of a picture.

Comment: This is vb.net not vba

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help

Comment: I would recommend using Linq to Xml instead of XmlSerializer - it's more lightweight and allows navigating the Xml. This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066213/linq-to-xml-in-vb-net) contains some simple examples that should help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already mentioned by Pawel you should rather use Linq to Xml.

Your sample program would look like:

```
Imports System.Linq
...

Sub Main()
    Dim input As XElement = XElement.Load("e:\Test\test2.xml") 

    //Query your Xml with Linq, almost similiar to Sql. 
    //You can extend with any where/join/group/order by clause
    Dim output = From activies In input...<activity>
                 Where Integer.Parse(activies.<memno>.Value) <= 1293
                 Select activies

    //Output is an IEnumarable of XElement
    For Each activity In output
        Console.WriteLine("Member: {0}", activity.<memno>.Value)
        Console.WriteLine("Current Week: {0}", activity.<curweek>.Value)
        //...
    Next

End Sub
```

As you can see you can navigate directly thru an XElement with `.<ChildElementName>` and with `...<DescendantElementName>` which is a pretty nice VB .NET feature.

More about [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb387098.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would read it to a dataset like this:

```
 Dim XML_Read as DataSet = new DataSet
 XML_Read.ReadXML("e:\Test\test2.xml")
```

Then you will get access to the element you want this way:

```
 XML_Read.tables("activity").Rows(0).Item("memno")
```